# Codeigniter Active Record too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, activerecord

I created "admin menu" for a translations of my webpage, picture included so you are in picture.
[image: picture]

It is pretty simple, I save everything to database and when I make change I regenerate desired files eg. `/languages/english/tank_auth_lang.php`. Whenever I want to translate/edit something I just click on field edit and click out of field AJAX sends POST to my controller that takes care of inserting/updating/adding translation.

**problem**

This is my function that works, but whenever I do **fast** resending (re-editing/adding new translations to the table) sometimes I get **duplicate** in database. Is there anything I should avoid doing? (like wait before sending or something).

If I do profiling it shows me that there are 2 same inserts (not in one AJAX call, but in two consecutive **fast** AJAX calls).

Function itself is complicated at first because whenever there is longer (`strlen()`) value than 524 I save it differently (I save it in table with structure `TEXT` not `VARCHAR(524)`).

**function**

```
public function insert() {
    //this function is used only with AJAX
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE); //to work profiler must be turned off

        $id_kw = $this->input->post('id_kw');
        $id_language = $this->input->post('id_language');
        $translation_text = $this->input->post('new_translation');


        if (strlen($translation_text) < '524') {
            //short
            if ($this->general_model->isInDBWhere('layout_short', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language))){
                //update short
                //get id of text_short and update text field in it
                $text_id = $this->general_model->_getColumnWhere('layout_short', 'id_text', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language));
                $this->general_model->updateRow('text_short', $text_id, array('text' => $translation_text));
                unset($text_id);
            }elseif ($this->general_model->isInDBWhere('layout_long', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language))) {

                $text_id = $this->general_model->_getColumnWhere('layout_long', 'id_text', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language)); //old text_id
                $this->general_model->_deleteWhere('text_long', array('id' => $text_id));
                $this->general_model->_deleteWhere('layout_long', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language));
                //insert new entry to short

                $this->_insert($table = 'short', $id_kw, $id_language, $translation_text);
            }else{
                //insert in short
                $this->_insert($table = 'short', $id_kw, $id_language, $translation_text);
            }
        }else{
            //long
            if ($this->general_model->isInDBWhere('layout_long', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language))){
                //update long
                //get id of text_long and update text field in it
                $text_id = $this->general_model->_getColumnWhere('layout_long', 'id_text', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language));
                $this->general_model->updateRow('text_long', $text_id, array('text' => $translation_text));
                unset($text_id);
            }elseif ($this->general_model->isInDBWhere('layout_short', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language))) {

                $text_id = $this->general_model->_getColumnWhere('layout_short', 'id_text', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language)); //old text_id
                $this->general_model->_deleteWhere('text_short', array('id' => $text_id));
                $this->general_model->_deleteWhere('layout_short', array('id_keyword' => $id_kw, 'id_language' => $id_language));
                //insert new entry to long

                $this->_insert($table = 'long', $id_kw, $id_language, $translation_text);
            }else{
                //insert in short
                $this->_insert($table = 'long', $id_kw, $id_language, $translation_text);
            }
        }
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".ajax-translate-field").on("focusout", function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('name'));
    console.log($(this).attr('data-language'));
    console.log($(this).val());
    var this_object = $(this);
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF9494', opacity: '0.6'}, "slow");
        this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: '1'}, "fast");
    }else{

        $.ajax({
            url: _baseUrl + 'admin/language/insert',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_kw: $(this).prop('name'), id_language : $(this).attr('data-language'), new_translation: $(this).val()},
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#BCED91', opacity: '0.6'}, "slow");
                    this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: '1'}, "fast");
                }else{
                    //nothing happens here yet
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post your javascript.

Comment: If it's two consecutive ajax calls than the problem is in your javascript not your controller

Comment: you need to assign a sort of `transaction_id` to the form, if you are already processing that transaction ignore it. To work out the transaction_id you could either hash the form values to get a unique one for each change or a fixed one on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your java-script to

```
var flag = 0;


$(".ajax-translate-field").on("focusout", function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('name'));
    console.log($(this).attr('data-language'));
    console.log($(this).val());
    var this_object = $(this);
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF9494', opacity: '0.6'}, "slow");
        this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: '1'}, "fast");
    }else if(flag != $(this).prop('name')){
        flag = $(this).prop('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: _baseUrl + 'admin/language/insert',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_kw: $(this).prop('name'), id_language : $(this).attr('data-language'), new_translation: $(this).val()},
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#BCED91', opacity: '0.6'}, "slow");
                    this_object.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: '1'}, "fast");
                }else{
                    //nothing happens here yet
                }
            },
            complete: function (result) { flag = 0;}
        });
    }

});
```

I assume `$(this).prop('name')` is unique key(id) in your code..

Comment: yes `$this.prop('name')` is unique id, I am going to try this out.

Comment: @Kyslik: In `Complete` method set the `flag = 0;`